# Pasar un Formulario como parámetro a una rutina de un módulo

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

En VB6 usaba la rutina ActBotones para habilitar/desabilitar los botones de acción de todas mis formas

```
' Actualizar botones Nuevo, modificar, gragar y eliminar
' Vrx   = Accion ( 0 = Nuevo, 1 = Modificar, -1 = Retorno Botones)
Sub ActBotones(fForm as Form, Vrx As Integer)
    If Vrx = 0 Then
        fForm.cmdMod.Enabled = False
        fForm.cmdElim.Enabled = False
        fForm.cmdGba.Enabled = True
    ElseIf Vrx = 1 Then
        fForm.cmdNvo.Enabled = False
        fForm.cmdElim.Enabled = False
        fForm.cmdGba.Enabled = True
    ElseIf Vrx = -1 Then
        fForm.cmdMod.Enabled = True
        fForm.cmdNvo.Enabled = True
        If Drx Then
            fForm.cmdElim.Enabled = True
        End If
        fForm.cmdGba.Enabled = False
    Else
        fForm.cmdMod.Enabled = False
        fForm.cmdNvo.Enabled = True
        fForm.cmdElim.Enabled = False
        fForm.cmdGba.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Hay alguna manera de haces esto en VB.Net para no tener que escribir el código tantas veces como formas tenga?

Answer (score 1):

También se puede aprovechar la ventaja que ofrece **.Net** al permitir [herencia](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/5x4yd9d5(v=vs.90).aspx), algo que en la versión 6 no se podía realizar, por lo menos no en forma directa.

En este caso sería de ayuda la *[herencia visual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bx1155fz(v=vs.110).aspx)*. Si colocamos en un `FormBase` los cuatro `Buttons` con sus funcionalidades, cuando se necesite un `FormX` con las mismas propiedades y métodos, sólamente se necesitaría que `FormX` [herede](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-AR/library/c8shwxa5.aspx) de `FormBase`, lo que ahorrará mucho tiempo, ya que la codificación se hizo una sola vez, en `FormBase`.

Pasos a seguir:

1. Se añade un nuevo `Form` al proyecto, dándole el nombre de `FormBase`, por ejemplo.
2. Se colocan todos los controles, en este caso:

   ```
   NuevoButton
   GuardarButton
   EditarButton    
   EliminarButton
   ```
3. Se le agrega todo el código para estos controles:

   ```vb
   Public Class FormBase

       Private Sub NuevoButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles NuevoButton.Click
           Me.EditarButton.Enabled = False
           Me.EliminarButton.Enabled = False
       End Sub

       Private Sub EditarButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles EditarButton.Click
           Me.NuevoButton.Enabled = False
           Me.EliminarButton.Enabled = False
       End Sub

       Private Sub GuardarButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles GuardarButton.Click
           Me.NuevoButton.Enabled = True
           Me.EditarButton.Enabled = True
           Me.EliminarButton.Enabled = True
       End Sub
   End Class
   ```
4. Para tener otro `Form` con estos mismos controles y funcionamiento, sólo se debe aplicar herencia. Para esto se hace lo siguiente:

   4.1. Se añade un nuevo `Form` al proyecto, con el nombre `FormX`, por ejemplo.

   4.2. Se busca la línea:

   ```vb
   Partial Class FormX
       Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
   ```

   Esta línea se puede encontrar dentro del archivo `FormX.Designer.vb`, que se ubica en la rama `FormX.vb`. Para ver este archivo se debe hacer click en el botón ***"Mostrar todos los archivos***", que es el segundo, contado desde la izquierda, de los cuatro que tiene el *"Explorador de soluciones"*.

   4.3. Se reemplaza `System.Windows.Forms.Form` por `FormBase`, quedando:

   ```vb
   Partial Class FormX
       Inherits FormBase
   ```

Listo, ya se tiene un nuevo `Form` con toda la funcionalidad de ´FormBase´, ahorrándose el diseñado y el código.

El detalle a tener en cuenta es que los controles heredados estarán bloqueados en tiempo de diseño, por lo cual, si se requiere realizar alguna acción sobre ellos, será necesario hacerlo en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: Igual valdria solo heredar codigo del form base y reescribir los controles si necesita reposicionarlos. Tambien podria generar una clase estatica con este metodo y llamarla con el form como parametro. Todo eso para evitar el problema de los controles estaticos.

Comment: Lo recomendado por Aprendiendo.NET no funciona en Visual Studio 2015. Lo probé y no hay manera. con VS 2015

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que podrias usar linq para localizar controles de forma dinamica y generica en el form

```
Button cmdMod = fForm.Controls.OfType(Of Button).FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = "cmdMod")

If cmdMod IsNot Nothing Then
  cmdMod.Enabled = False
EndIf
```

de esta forma buscas por nombre el control y si existe en la instancia del forma que proporcionas por parametro accederas al boton para trabajar sus propiedades